# va_start error on x64 arhitecture?

Tags: c++

I am having a hard time compiling my program in x64.
Whilst I was able to fix everything and compile, my program crashes at the logging:

```
void TLog::VLogAddFormat(COLORREF colorText, const char *& AddressOfFmt, ...)
{
    m_Sync.Lock();
    // ----
    PrepareLogBuff();
    // ---- 
    //setter(&AddressOfFmt, -32L);
    va_start(m_pArguments, AddressOfFmt);       // the real address of fmt. m_pArguments = (va_list)_ADDRESSOF(v) + _INTSIZEOF(v)
    vsprintf(m_LogTempBuff, AddressOfFmt, m_pArguments);
    va_end(m_pArguments); < BREAK HERE !
    // ----
    LogAddStr(colorText, m_LogTempBuff);
    // ----
    m_Sync.Unlock();
}
```

Notice that I have added the "**...**" because it would not compile otherwise.
Break occurs at: "**va_end(m_pArguments); < BREAK HERE !**"
And the strange problem is that in "**m_pArguments**" I get very strange characters...

Can somebody tell me how should I use va_start in x64? Many thanks.

Comment: The definition of va_start goes like `void va_start(va_list ap, last_arg)`, whereap is of va_list type object and last_arg is the **fixed argument**. Here, you've passed pointer reference in last_arg which is invalid.

Comment: Thanks for answering, but I need to see some example...

Comment: This [link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_macro_va_start.htm) contains an example.

Comment: Thanks! I will try now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't pass a reference parameter to `va_start`. It's undefined behaviour.

Comment: I noticed that... but what should I do then ?:(

Comment: Take `AddressOfFmt` by value and then return the new value and assign it after your call to `VLogAddFormat`.

Comment: Ok, you lost me ... :(

Comment: Why are you taking `AddressOfFmt` by reference? Because `setter(&AddressOfFmt, -32L)` modifies its value right? So you take `AddressOfFmt` by value, so `setter` modifies a temporary, and then you return `AddressOfFmt` from the function and assign the return value to whatever was being passed as `AddressOfFmt`.

Comment: setter does not work, I don`t know why, I couldn`t find the .h for setter

Comment: If you don't know how your own code is supposed to work how can anybody help you?